# Evaluate string expression in rust with conditionals

Tags: rust, eval

I am trying to evaluate a string in rust with conditionals using evalexpr module.
This results in the following error

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: AppendedToLeafNode', src\main.rs:6:56

The error description says
https://docs.rs/evalexpr/5.0.5/evalexpr/error/enum.EvalexprError.html#variant.AppendedToLeafNode

> Tried to append a child to a leaf node. Leaf nodes cannot have
> children.

I am not able to understand why this error is happening.  Does anyone have a clue?  Is it possible to evaluate an string with conditionals in Rust?

```rust
use evalexpr::*;
fn main() {
    let evalstr = "let x = if input == 8 { 3 } else { 4 };";
    let mut context = HashMapContext::new();
    context.set_value("input".into(), 8.into()).unwrap();
    eval_empty_with_context_mut(evalstr, &mut context).unwrap();
    let val = context.get_value("x").unwrap();
    println!("{}", val);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`evalexpr` doesn't support the Rust language, but uses its own little language documented here: https://docs.rs/evalexpr/6.6.0/evalexpr/index.html#features

That little language does not support conditionals yet: https://github.com/ISibboI/evalexpr/issues/82

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to implement a custom "if" function to achive this.

Answer (score 1):

Today, the rust `evalexpr` has a built-in `if` function: `if(condition, a, b)`